# How to implement asynchronous computed observable with multiple $.ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, knockout.js

I'm attempting to implement an asynchronous computed observable as show [here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/asynchronous-dependent-observables).

I can do it successfully for one ajax call. The challenge I have at the moment is how to perform various ajax  calls in a loop building an array asynchronously and then returning the array to my computed observable array using jQuery promises.

Basically the HTML form works in the following way:

1. This a student course form.
2. For each row, users type the person number and on another column they'll type a list of course ids separated by commas. Eg 100, 200, 300.
3. The purpose of the computed observable is to store an array
   containing course details for the courses entered in step 2.
4. The details are obtained by firing ajax calls for each course and storing HTTP response in the array.
5. I don't want users to wait for the result, thus the reason to implement an async computed observable.

My problem: I'm having problem returning the value of the final array to the observable. It's always undefined. The ajax calls work fine but perhaps I'm still not handling the promises correctly.

Here's the code for my class:

```
function asyncComputed(evaluator, owner) {
            var result = ko.observable(), currentDeferred;
            result.inProgress = ko.observable(false); // Track whether we're waiting for a result

            ko.computed(function () {
                // Abort any in-flight evaluation to ensure we only notify with the latest value
                if (currentDeferred) { currentDeferred.reject(); }

                var evaluatorResult = evaluator.call(owner);
                // Cope with both asynchronous and synchronous values
                if (evaluatorResult && (typeof evaluatorResult.done == "function")) { // Async
                    result.inProgress(true);
                    currentDeferred = $.Deferred().done(function (data) {
                        result.inProgress(false);
                        result(data);
                    });
                    evaluatorResult.done(currentDeferred.resolve);
                } else // Sync
                    result(evaluatorResult);
            });

            return result;
        }


        function personDetails(id, personNumber, courseIds) {
            var self = this;
            self.id = ko.observable(id);
            self.personNumber = ko.observable(personNumber);
            self.courseIds = ko.observable(courseIds);

            // Computed property to extract PIC details for additional PICs.
            // This is computed observable which returns response asynchronously
            self.courseDetails = asyncComputed(function () {
                var courseIdsArray = self.courseIds().split(",");
                var arr = [];
                var arr_promises = [];

                function getCourseDetails(courseId) {
                    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
                    var content = {};

                    content.searchString = courseId;

                    var url = 'MyURL';

                    return $.ajax(url, {
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: requestData, // content of requestData is irrelevant. The ajax call works fine.
                        processdata: true,
                        cache: false,
                        async: true,
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        arr.push(new PicDetails(data.GenericIdentifierSearchResult[0]));
                    }).fail(function () {
                        alert("Could not retrieve PIC details");
                    }).then(function () {
                        dfrd.resolve();
                    });

                }

                if (courseIdsArray.length > 0) {

                    $.each(courseIdsArray, function (index, courseId) {
                        if (courseId.length > 0) {
                            arr_promises.push(getCourseDetails(courseId));
                        }
                    });
                };

                $.when.apply($, arr_promises).done(function () {
                    return arr;
                })

            }, this);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something a bit different from your approach, but you can build something like an asyncComputed out of it if you prefer:

1. make a simple observable that will hold the result
2. make a dictionary of promises that you'll basically keep in sync with the array of course ids
3. when the array of course ids change, add / remove from the dictionary of promises
4. wrap all your promises in a `when` (like you're doing) and set the result when they're all done

Basic idea:

```
var results = ko.observable([]);
var loadingPromises = {};
var watcher = ko.computed(function () {

    var ids = ko.unwrap(listOfIds);

    if (ids && ids.length) {
        ids.forEach(function (id) {
            if (!loadingPromises.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                loadingPromises[id] = $.get(url, {...id...});
            }
        });

        var stillApplicablePromises = {};
        var promises = []; // we could delete from loadingPromises but v8 optimizes delete poorly
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(loadingPromises).forEach(function (id) {
            if (ids.indexOf(id) >= 0) {
                stillApplicablePromises[id] = loadingPromises[id];
                promises.push(loadingPromises[id]);
            }
        });
        loadingPromises = stillApplicablePromises;

        $.when.apply(this, promises).then(function () {
            // process arguments here however you like, they're the responses to your promises
            results(arguments);
        });

    } else {
        loadingPromises = {};
        results([]);
    }
}, this);
```

This is the file (that may change) where you can see this "in real life": https://github.com/wikimedia/analytics-dashiki/blob/master/src/components/wikimetrics-visualizer/wikimetrics-visualizer.js

And the basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xtsekb20/1/

Comment: Thank you @Milimetric - I'll try your approach and will let you know.

Comment: I have question referring the loadingPromises[id] = $.get(url, {...id...}); Do you return a promise to loadingPromises[id]?

Comment: yep, `$.get()` like `$.ajax()` returns a promise object.  So if you assign that to `loadingPromises[id]` then you have a promise to that url / id parameter until it's taken out of `listOfIds`.  This way, when a user changes `listOfIds` by only adding a new id, the old promises are still there and don't get re-fetched.

Comment: Is it something like $.ajax(url, {...data...}).then(function (data) { return data[0]};

Comment: in the code you wrote above, you're using the promise right away by calling `.then` on it.  In the code I'm suggesting above, you save the promise so you can pass all of your promises at the same time to `$.when`.  Or am I misunderstanding your misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm sorry @Milimetric this is new ground for me. Have a look at this JSFiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/xtsekb20/   The code if (loadingPromises.hasOwnProperty(id)) { doesn't evaluate to true and therefore ajax calls are not made. Could you please have a look at what I'm returning in the GetPicDetails function.

Comment: No problem!  I'm just excited that I did basically the same exact thing you're trying to do :)

Comment: Ok, fiddle looks a little better now: http://jsfiddle.net/xtsekb20/1/ .  Changes: fixed `self` variable, fixed `!loadingPromises.hasOwnProperty(id)` instead of the silly way I had it before, fixed a few function names and little errors.

Comment: Hey @Milimetric - It worked brilliantly!! I appreciate the time you took to answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont really need a separate api/code for this.

You could just create observables for every input/value that changes on your site, and create a computed observable based on those.

e.g in rough pseudo code

```
self.id           = ko.observable(id);
self.personNumber = ko.observable(personNumber);
self.courseIds    = ko.observable(courseIds);
self.courseDetailsArray = ko.observableArray([]);
self.courseDetails = ko.computed(function() {
    //computed the course details based on other observables
    //whenever user types in more course ids, start loading them
    $.get( yoururl, {self.courseIds and self.id}).success(data) {
        when finished async loading, parse the data and push the new course details into final array
        self.courseDetailsArray.push( your loaded and parsed data );
        //since courseDetailsArray is observableArray, you can have further computed observables     using and re-formatting it.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rainer Plumer - The issue I have here is that I cannot make one ajax call with all course ids. I have to call the web service for each course id and store details in array. Only after the array is completed I should return it to the computed observable. The value of the computed observable depends on multiple ajax calls. The number of calls will will depend on the number of courses.

Comment: Why do you need to wait until all of the id's have finished loading ?

Why dont you just push the loaded data into observable array one by one. The only downside/(or benefit) is that the user interface gets re-rendered every time a new item is added. This can be both good( user sees the loading progress) or bad( page speed). The speed shouldnt be an issue since the user cant really type in the ids that fast to make significant performance impact. You can also define a delay for the observable update, so that it isnt updated that often..giving you time to load other items.